# git: track a remote branch not on origin

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

My situation is thus:

I do work on two different machines, both of which track a repository (**origin**) cloned from another source (git.domain_name).

One one machine, **my_machine1**, I've created a branch to add some functionality, we'll call it *myFoo*.

One the other machine (**my_machine2**), I'd like to track (and be able to update and push to **my_machine1**) the *myFoo* branch.

On **my_machine2**, I've done `git remote add my_machine1 my_user@my_machine1:/path/to/common/repo`

But if I do a `git branch -a` I don't see any branches from **my_machine1**, only from **origin**. I can see branches on **my_machine1** if I do a `git ls-branch my_machine1`. Pushing *myFoo* to origin is not an option.

Is there some way to track/share the *myFoo* branch between **my_machine1** and **my_machine2**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a remote doesn't fetch the stuff, you still have to `git fetch my_machine1`

Comment: alternatlively, "git remote update" works too. The -f option to git add does the fetch just after the add, which is great to check that there are no mistakes in the newly added remote.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the suggested git fetch, "git remote update" works too (will fetch all remotes).

Also, the -f option to git add does the fetch just after the add, which is great to check that there are no mistakes in the newly added remote

Answer (score 1):

Note: `git remote update` will always fetch *all* the remotes, like a `git fetch --all` would (see "[git remote update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856499/git-remote-update)")

As mentioned in "[What is the difference between `git fetch origin` and `git remote update origin`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688251/what-is-the-difference-between-git-fetch-origin-and-git-remote-update-origin)", `remote update` is a very high-level command

> - it supports grouped remotes (`remotes.<group> = <list>`),
> - and updating all remotes (except those with `remote.<name>.skipDefaultUpdate` set),
> - but not any of the more specific options of `fetch`.

Git fetch also supports groups of repos:

```
$ git config remotes.mygroup 'remote1 remote2 ...'
$ git fetch mygroup
```

So for just *one* remote repo (`origin`), `git fetch` is both more precise and offers more options than `git remote update`.