# What is the difference between 'git remote update', 'git fetch' and 'git pull'?

Tags: git

I'm starting to play with Git now and I'm a little bit confused. For me, looks like there are a lot of options to do the same thing. My question for now is what is the difference between the commands below:

- git remote update
- git fetch
- git pull

Also which one is more applicable for update a local copy of a remote branch?

Comment: See [Differences between git remote update and fetch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856499/differences-between-git-remote-update-and-fetch), and also [What is the difference between `git fetch origin` and `git remote update origin`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688251/what-is-the-difference-between-git-fetch-origin-and-git-remote-update-origin).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/whats-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch).

Answer (score 135, accepted):

`git remote update` will update all of your branches set to track remote ones, but not merge any changes in.

`git fetch` will update only the branch you're on, but not merge any changes in.

`git pull` will update *and* merge any remote changes of the current branch you're on.  This would be the one you use to update a local branch.

Comment: `git fetch` will update other branches, if you want.  Try `git fetch --all`

Comment: Did you know you can actually do fast-forward merges with fetch by using refspecs?: `git fetch origin master:master`. That only works if you don't have `master` checked out though, because Git has to move the branch pointer and won't do it if you're currently on the branch.

Comment: 'get fetch' seems to fetch all branches when I do it, even without using the --all switch.(Git for windows 2.10.0.1)

Comment: @ColinDBennett: That was a ***significant*** change to an older post.  If you feel like an answer warrants that much detail, it'd be better for you to post your own answer.

Comment: This answer has several errors.  Mostly they come from confusing the *remote tracking branches* with regular branches, which is a big mistake.  `git fetch` does not update the "branch you're on".  But it does update all remote tracking branches for the remote `origin` or whatever remote the upstream tracking branch for the current remote is.

Comment: Also see the VERY complete answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/17512004/994153 which describes how `git fetch --all` didn't exist at one time, so `git remote update` what more useful.  Now that `--all` has been added to `git fetch`, `git remote update` is not really necessary.

Comment: `git fetch --all` does not fetch all branches; it fetches from all remotes.

Comment: I have a project with several sub-modules.  Did a git clone, then git submodule init step. Everthing was fine, able to build, no problems.

Now, I want to update *everything* to latest HEAD, so I "git pull".   I see git accessing submodules.  But "git status" shows some submodules modified (New Commits), I didn't modify anything in those.

I change into those directories, and do a git pull, I see a "HEAD detached".

How does that make sense ? Why would the head be detached ?  (git == overcomplicated !) 

What is the command to pull *everything*  (make me fully up to date )?

Comment: `git fetch` support concurrent updates (`-j/--jobs`), `git remote update` does not.

Comment: The `git remote update` command is used to fetch updates from all of your remotes, NOT branches.

Answer (score -7):

Not sure about the git remote update, but git pull is the git fetch followed automatically by a git merge...

This is partially a duplicate. Check:
[What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/whats-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Also, if it means anything to you, I've never used git remote update neither fgit fetch.
You can do just fine with pull, commit and push.

Hope it helps..

Comment: `git fetch` has its place...sometimes you only care about how many branches your manager has pruned; sometimes you only want the updates from the branch you're on.

Comment: I guess it makes sense =)

Comment: I almost never use `git pull`, I always like to preview any upstream changes before I merge them in, so I mostly use `git fetch`.

Comment: Usually you don't want to merge your local work-in-progress branch to master yet, so it's better to `git remote update` and `git rebase` until your work is ready to be merged. Otherwise you'll just end up with a number of useless merge commits in the history.