# git branch unkown but checkout works

Tags: git, version-control, git-remote

on my remote repository a new branch has been created. In GitBash in my Working Directory (on master branch) I type `git remote update` and `git pull`. To my understanding `git remote update` will update all branches set to track remote ones as explained here:
[What is the difference between 'git remote update', 'git fetch' and 'git pull'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712468/what-is-the-difference-between-git-remote-update-git-fetch-and-git-pull)

So when I type `git diff master newBranch --name-only` I expected to see a list of files which are different in both branches. But instead I got the following error message:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'newBranch': unknown revision or path not in
>   the working tree.

But if I type `git checkout newBranch` it works fine, and if I switch back to master by typing `git checkout master` suddenly `git diff master newBranch --name-only` works perfectly?

Could anyone explain to me this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you don't have the local copy of the branch "newBranch" so you need to specify that you want to do a diff with the branch tag from the remote like this:

```
git diff origin/master origin/newBranch --name-only
```

or assuming you have the master locally:

```
git diff master origin/newBranch --name-only
```

Check which branches you have locally:

```
git branch -l
```

or

```
git branch
```

check remote branches

```
git branch -r
```

check all branches:

```
git branch -a
```

So this worked for you after you did a checkout because git automatically created a local branch called newBranch. So before your checkout `git branch` would not show a branch called "newBranch" but after the checkout it would.

Answer (score 1):

When you typed `git diff master newBranch --name-only` for first time, you had not any local `newBranch` branch. So, it gives the error:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'newBranch': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Later when you checked out to the **newBranch** by `git checkout newBranch` command, a new local branch is created. So, next time `git diff master newBranch --name-only` is working as well.

**Note:** `git checkout newBranch` actually finds a local `newBranch` branch if found then switch to the branch. But if not found then finds in remote branch lists if found then create a new local `newBranch` branch tracking the remote `newBranch` branch.