# cleartool find difference recursive in certain file type to predecessor

Tags: version-control, clearcase, difference

In my script I'm calling ClearCase to check if any file of a certain file type in the current path (including all subfolders) has been changed. I'm not familiar with cleartool at all, the command should like this:

> cleartool diff -predecessor -recursive *.filetype

As a return value I only need a bool: true if any differences exist, false if nothing has changed

Comment: It is better to not use wildcard for your cleartool diff, but rather combine a find query: I'll post an answer later today

Comment: What is the underlying purpose of the request? If you're running this as a scheduled job to trigger a build, this would be returning "it changed" almost every time if all the files in question are checked in. (Unless checkin -identical is a normal occurrence in your location.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As a return value I only need a bool: true if any differences exist, false if nothing has changed

You need a script. A simple find + exec won't be enough, because the exit status won't be exactly what you need.

```
#! /bin/bash
noChange=0  ### "cleartool diff" exit status means no difference
files=$(cleartool find . -name "*.filetype")
for f in ${file}; do;
  cleartool diff -pre -options "-status_only" "${f}"
  if [ $? != $noChange ]; then
    exit 0
  fi
done
exit 1
```

([0 is true, false is 1 in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2933855/6309))

Note the use, in [`cleartool diff`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diff.htm) of the `-options` parameter:

```
opt/ions pass-through-opts
```

> Specifies one or more compare method options that are not directly supported by diff.

That way, you get only the status from `cleartool diff`, which is precisely what you want to test in your case.

Since your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44695733/6309) shows you have Git too, you can easily execute that script in a bash session, even on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

On first glance, the command you're looking for is something like this:

```
cleartool find . -name "*.filetype" -exec 'cleartool diff -pred "$CLEARCASE_PN"'
```

On windows, it would look like this:

```
cleartool find . -name "*.filetype" -exec "cleartool diff -pred \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

The single quotes in the Unix example are significant since otherwise the "CLEARCASE_PN" environment variable reference would be expanded at the time you start the command and not when the -exec is actually fired.

The \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\" construct in the Windows command line and the "$CLEARCASE_PN" on unix is to account for filenames including spaces.

Now, looking at what you want... I'm not sure it would accomplish the underlying purpose, whatever that is.