# How can I check in interval loop if the tags exist before doing the `git checkout $tag` command?

Tags: linux, bash, git, debian, sh

In a bash script, I am waiting for a particular remote git tag to be released before using it in my script.

How can I check in interval loop if the tags exist before doing the `git checkout $tag` command?

Ex:

```
 while sleep 3; do git fetch && git rev-parse --verify <tag> && break; done
```

**Edit**

I have created the following bash functions:

```sh
function wait_for_tag() {
  tag=v${1#v}
  interval=${2:-20}
    while :; do

        echo "Waiting for tag ${tag}..."
        git remote update > /dev/null 2>&1
        git rev-parse --verify --quiet "${tag}" && break
        sleep ${interval}
    done
}

function git_checkout() {
  tag=v${1#v}
    is_release && wait_for_tag "${tag}"
    git checkout ${tag} || echo "testing"
    npm install
}
```

I expect when I do `git_checkout v2.0.13-bs-redux-saga-router-dom-intl` to checkout the tag if it is already existing, otherwise, to fetch for new tags and try again later.

This seems to work nice in a local environment, but when I do that in Gitlab-CI, the parallel pipelines are never seeing the new tag, even if they are tagged and existing on Gitlab UI.

How can I ensure that the `wait_for_tag` function does really retrieve tags and why does `git remote update` fail to do that?

Comment: Don't poll, have your upstream send out notifications in its post-receive or update hook.

Comment: The user would still be running `git` repeatedly to trigger either hook; `git` itself doesn't do asynchronous notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git rev-parse` to check weather the tag exists or not:

```sh
git rev-parse -q --verify "refs/tags/$tag" >/dev/null
```

In a loop you've mentioned and in combination with `git checkout` it could look like this:

```sh
tag="foo"
while true; do
    git fetch --all
    if git rev-parse -q --verify "refs/tags/$tag" >/dev/null; then
        git checkout "$tag" && break
    fi
    sleep 5
done
```

In this case you really have to pass a *tag name* as `$tag` - no commit hash or branch.

Comment: You are not fetching the tag, it might hang, and you are not using interval, it might spam the backend git server

Comment: I've edited the code ;) I thought the "git rev-parse" was the part you were asking about and not the shell scripting part.

Comment: This will keep checking out the tag once it is available. You might want to add a break after the checkout.

Comment: It work but I had to do `git fetch --tags` instead of `git fetch --all` otherwise, even if the tag was present serverside, it was hanging

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git rev-parse` to check if the tag exists.  Something like this:

```
while :; do
  git remote update
  git rev-parse --verify --quiet SomeInterestingTag && break

  # the tag did not exist
  sleep 10
done
```

Comment: what's the difference of using `git remote update` than `git fetch` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712468/what-is-the-difference-between-git-remote-update-git-fetch-and-git-pull

Comment: There is not a substantial difference between the two answers. It looks like we both answered at about the same time.  Pick one! :)