# Git pull just one commit

Tags: git

Actually the git repository and local files are exactly the same.

But the other website is far away from 5 commits, so I haven't pull in a while and I don't want to do it neither.

So now I wanna do some change in my local files and then push that into a new commit to git repository, THEN only be able to PULL that one commit and not all the others ... can I do this??

I don't even want to delete the commits there, just I want to be able to pull 1 commit, I hope you can help me

Comment: This is why you shouldn't develop on the master branch.

Comment: You can create a patch, or push the commit to a new branch and cherry pick from there

Comment: This is the first result after googling your question title: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680426/how-to-pull-one-commit-at-a-time-from-a-remote-git-repository Did you see that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to pull one commit, you can simply 'reset' to that commit..

```
git reset --hard <commit>
```

You could also make a new branch *foo* off that commit and pull only that branch down to your new environment. This will help maintain your codebase as you can continue to work on your original branch without having to think about affecting the new site.

```
git checkout -b foo
```

this is shorthand for

```
git branch foo
git checkout foo
```

You can then pull that branch onto whatever machine with

```
git clone -b *foo* http//dude@:bitbucket.org
```

or something like

```
git clone -b *foo* ssh://git@bitbucket.org/path/to/repo.git
```

Answer (score 17):

`git pull` is essentially a shorthand for `git fetch` (download remote commits into remote-tracking branches) and then `git merge` (merge your `HEAD`, i.e. the current commit, with the ones you just downloaded).

You can get the flexibility you expect by decoupling both steps:

- First, run `git fetch`, then inspect the history you just downloaded (if you work on the `master` branch, `git fetch` should have downloaded remote commits in branch `origin/master` which you can inspect with `git log origin/master`).
- Then, merge the commit you want using `git merge <commit>`. Note: `git merge` will get all the changes in `<commit>` and its ancestry, so this works if `<commit>` is the oldest non-merged commit. If you do not have any unpushed commits, this will "fast-forward", i.e. it won't create a new commit but just advance `HEAD` to this commit. If you're not happy with `git merge`, you have other options like `git rebase`, `git cherry-pick`, ...

Answer (score 12):

Assuming your remote is `origin` and your branch is `master`,

`git fetch && git merge $(git rev-list master..origin/master | tail -n1)`

This will:

1. Run `git fetch` to update `origin/master`
2. Get the list of commit hashes (`git rev-list`) from after `master` up to `origin/master`, and get the last line (`tail`), i.e., the first new commit
3. Pass the result of the last step to `git merge`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git cherry-pick <commit>` to do this.

Just copy the commit you want to add and it adds it.
Beware: I guess, it only adds the changes of the commit, and no other in-between commits are fetched.